# Delete operation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding delete operation in javascript.

I have an object like follows -

```
var object = {"name" : "abc"};

object.prototype = {"name" : "xyz"};
```

If I delete the "name" property from object it should delete it from the object and not from the prototype as the prototype values are only used in get operation.

So after -

```
delete object.name
```

If I print object.name it gives me 'undefined', while in my opinion it should give me 'xyz'.

First i thought that the delete operation is just setting the value of object.name to 'undefined', but then object.hasOwnProperty('name') gives me false.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: _If I print object.name it gives me 'undefined', while in my opinion it should give me 'xyz'._ It seems that you confuse `object.name` and `object.prototype.name`

Comment: The behavior you describe would occur only if the prototype occurs in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 7):

The hole in your understanding is with prototypes, not delete.

Values on the prototype appear on *instances* of an object, not the object to which the prototype property belongs.

You need to create a constructor function, put the prototype on that, then instantiate an object from that function using `new`.

```js
function MyObject (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

MyObject.prototype.name = "xyz";

var instance = new MyObject("abc");

document.write(instance.name);
document.write("<br>");
delete instance.name;
document.write(instance.name);
```

Comment: Great answer but I'm struggling with "Values on the prototype appear on instances of an object, not the object to which the prototype property belongs" - can anyone expand a little, please?

Comment: @WillJenkins — Umm. I did. In the next paragraph.